# listing the names and the attributes of factories (FactoryGirl)

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I want to write a ruby script to list the names and their attributes of factories in a project (with `factory girl`).
My problem is, I'm not sure how can I determine the `start` and `end` of a given factory

The approach I'm thinking is to,

- start reading each factory file as a string
- when I get the string `factory`, I assume its the starting of a
  factory. (and I get the starting position)
- then I read on the file until I get an `end` and if it is in align
  with the `factory` I assume  its the end of the factory

But the downside of this is, If the alignments are different I will not be able to determine the end point of the factory.

My questions are,

- Is this a good approach ?
- What are the alternatives ?

I checked `rubocop`, and their approach to handle alignments, but seems like since its a general approach, its complicated. I believe their should be an easier way.

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Testing-all-Factories-(with-RSpec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like quite a bit of overkill. You can just ask FactoryGirl itself, since each `Factory` has an **[`attributes` object](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb#L108-L113)** and **[name](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb#L78-L80)** associated with it.

Comment: @Jhon, thanks a lot for the answer, quick question through, since I'm going to use this from a outside app (like `code climate`), will it work?, coz I cannot load the factory inside the project itself (where the factory is belongs to)

Comment: @sameera207 You can still load the project that corresponds to the factories (e.g. if they're all in `spec/factories`, load that and any dependencies).

Comment: @Jhon, thanks , I think your approach is the correct way. (but I'm yet to try it). I believe https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-without-bundler will help me to load the factories from a different rails project..

Answer (score 1):

If you need to actually parse the `factories.rb` file and can't just execute the Ruby, I'd strongly recommend using a true parser like [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) instead of writing a string parser for Ruby yourself.